# Visual studio uses the wrong ascii table?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, assembly, ascii

I've been trying to work with ascii characters in assembly. In particular, with the extended ascii table (255 characters). In my code i get two characters, i use the ADD function to sum their ascii values and then print the corresponding character. For example, the sum of two values gives 147, which is the character " ô ", while Visual Studio tells me the corresponding character is " " ". The overflow flag gives 1, so i guess Visual Studio works with the wrong Ascii table. The characters i use for the add function never went over 127, so it shouldn't be greater than 255. What should i do?

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) isn't defined beyond 127. You may want to try [`<wchar.h>` and friends](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/wchar.h.html)

Comment: Do you mean the x86 [`add`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add) instruction?  It's not a function, it's an instruction.  But yes, it just does integer addition.  The Overflow flag (OF) is set because adding two positive produced a negative result (aka 128..255 unsigned).  http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt.  How you got the number isn't significant.  `mov eax, 147` would have the same effect.

Comment: Also, I assume you already know this since you didn't ask, but if you're adding ASCII digits, you can subtract `'0'` to correct the single-digit result.  Like `'2' + '3' - '0' = '5'`.  So `lea eax, [eax + ecx - '0']` is one easy way to do that, but of course that only works for single-digit inputs and results.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of project (console app, windows forms app) you are making, dealing with code pages can be very tricky.
You have to make sure, that your source code is the same code page as you are using in the application, and it depends on wether you are using ASCII, UTF8, Unicode, MBCS and so on.

I do not know any exact sources for this, but you have to read through the internet on localisation, codepages and ASCII, UTF8, Unicode, and so on...

Greetings
Wolfgang